# Building a custom array from a MySQL result set

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following table with images for a blog post:

```
+----+---------+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| id | id_post | imagine                | descriere | tip       | sters |
+----+---------+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
|  1 |       4 | asdasdsadasdasdasd.jpg | NULL      | thumbnail |     0 |
|  2 |       4 | asdasdsadasdasdasd.jpg | NULL      | full      |     0 |
|  3 |       4 | asdasdsadasdasdasd.jpg | NULL      | thumbnail |     0 |
|  4 |       4 | asdasdsadasdasdasd.jpg | NULL      | full      |     0 |
+----+---------+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

In this table there's a column named "tip" (or type, in english) which represents the image type: full screen, or thumbnail. When someone uploads an image, there will always be a pair of "full" and "thumbnail" entries.

What I'm trying to do is to get all the images for a post and store them into an array, but with a single entry for each image like this: Array ( [0] => Array ( [thumbnail] => "1.jpg", [full] => "11.jpg")...

Comment: how do you know that image X is the thumb image Y (so that you can group them) ?

Answer (score 1):

Select your table and follow this code,

```
$array[]= array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    //using 2-d array
    $array[$row[id]][$row[tip]]= $row[imagine];
}
```

Now when you want to retrieve images for specific post, you can use

```
$array[$post_id]['full']
$array[$post_id]['thumbnail']
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, 1st, you need some kind of variable, that binds the `full` image with the `thumbnail` image. Currenty there is no way telling witch thumbnail goes to witch image.
Add a field like `full_id` or just combine the entries into one line, like:

```
+----+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------+
| id | id_post | imagine_full | imagine_thumb | descriere | sters |
+----+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------+
```

After that, use a loop to go through your values like @voodoo417 showed:

```
$items = array();

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
    $items[] = array( 
                 'thumbnail' => $row['imagine_thumb'],
                 'full' => $row['imagine_full']
            );
}
```

Comment: +1 As there is always a thumb and full image, storing them together is a good idea. And watch out for the witches LOL

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$items = array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array(RESOURSE)){
 $items[] = array( 'thumbnail'=>$row['thumbnail'], 'full' =>$row['full'] );
}
```

Comment: thumbnail and full are on separate rows! so this will not work